# Chrome does not fire change event on file input when second (only) file (different) selected

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

User can select more than one file to post. When using Chrome after first file selected and li element added to list, second file selection does not trigger the change event. Third do.

User can select different files. Clear input value does not help. No double click, use Open button in file selection dialog.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="attachments">
    <p id="add-file-button">Add file</p>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
<script>
    $('#add-file-button').on('click', function () {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'file';
        var $input = $(input);
        $input.hide();

        $input.on('change', function (e) {
            var $li = $('<li></li>');
            $li.append($input);

            $li.append(e.target.files[0].name);

            $('#attachments ul').append($li);
        });

        $input.trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

Reproduced on Chrome 75.0.3770.142 on different workstations.
How to fix it?

Comment: Because you are explicitly stating Chrome: Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: Edge - ok. But Edge has more other bugs. :)

Comment: did you try event delegation? https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events.
Maybe try ` $input.change();` aswell, this is the common way to trigger a change for an input in jquery

Comment: Works fine for me on chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/au9x3g4b/ You can click add file n-times and it always adds the selected file. Or do I miss the point here?

Comment: Try it on clear page. No other markup or code. Local page fails too.